# Mysql 'between' condition not working if value is greater than 9999 with varchar field

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL `between` does not work if the range goes above 9999.

The field type is varchar.

It works properly if the range is below 9999.

Query listed below :

```
SELECT `restaurant_details`.*
from restaurant_details 
Where `restaurant_details`.`value` BETWEEN '8001' AND '12000'
```

Comment: Can you show the column you're querying?

Comment: varchar doesn't work like this. it sorts alphabetical, not numerical

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE restaurant_details` please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can cast your `VARCHAR` to `INTEGER ( UNSIGNED )` to make a proper comparison:

```
SELECT `restaurant_details`.*
from restaurant_details 
Where CAST(`restaurant_details`.`value` AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 8001 AND 12000
```

**EDIT:** forgot to mention that you also have to drop the quotes around the numbers (8001 and 12000 in this case) so `MySQL` interprets them as `integers` as well.

Answer (score 1):

To figure out what is wrong, ask yourself the question, what strings come between '8001' AND '12000'?  That is, what expression is greater than '8' and less than '1'.

The answer is no character is both greater than `8` and less than `1`.  You probably want to convert the character string to an integer—or float if decimals appear in the data.

Comment: values are available in database and working if I modify range like '8000' AND '9999'. but when I increase it no results fetched

Comment: because 1 is smaller than 8. it's a string.

Comment: @Krishna:  Exactly.  Up to 9999 it is possible for there to be matches.  Note that `81000` *also* matches!